# Columna desconocida en MySql cuando sí existe

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

estoy realizando una página en php con una base de datos SQL usando WorkBench, el problema viene cuando intento insertar un nuevo registro en una tabla llamada `comentario`, entre los campos se encuentra una fecha con nombre `fecha_comentario`, pues bien, al ver que cada vez que intentaba insertar dentro de la tabla un nuevo registro me saltaba el error `1054 Unknown column 'fecha_comentario' in 'field list'` decidí cambiarle el nombre a `fecha_comentario` por `fechaComentario` pero nada, sigue saltandome el `error 1054` pero lo curioso es que el nombre de la columna desconocida sigue siendo `fecha_comentario` cuando ya no existe, simplemente no entiendo nada, he probado de todo.

Esta es la creación de la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `esquema`.`comentario` (
  `idComentario` INT NOT NULL,
  `login_usuario_comentario` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `mensaje_comentario` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `idPublicacion_comentario` INT NOT NULL,
  `fechaComentario` DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idComentario`, `login_usuario_comentario`),
  INDEX `fk_comentario_publicacion_idx` (`idPublicacion_comentario` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_comentario_usuario_idx` (`login_usuario_comentario` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_comentario_publicacion`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idPublicacion_comentario`)
    REFERENCES `esquema`.`publicacion` (`idPublicacion`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_comentario_usuario`
    FOREIGN KEY (`login_usuario_comentario`)
    REFERENCES `esquema`.`usuario` (`login`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
```

La tabla formada sería la siguiente:

| idComentario | login_usuario_comentario | mensaje_comentario | idPublicacion_comentario | fechaComentario |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

si trato de hacer una consulta `SELECT fechaComentario FROM comentario` funciona perfectamente y me devuelve todas las fechas que tengo almacenadas en la tabla,
sin embargo si trato de hacer un `INSERT INTO comentario VALUES("1", "usu", "mensaje", "1", "2022-05-24")` me da el `1054 Unknown column 'fecha_comentario' in 'field list'` cuando `fecha_comentario` era el antiguo nombre del campo `fechaComentario`

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! tenes un trigger que apunta a esa columna...

Answer (score 0):

Lo he resuelto gracias a un comentario de [gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi) indicando que tenía un trigger tratando de acceder a `fecha_comentario` cuando esta columna efectivamente no existía.